# Subtract 1 from a large number in PHP

Tags: php

I need to subtract 1 from the number `294867828828426241` in PHP. However when I do

```
$a = 294867828828426241 - 1;
```

I receive the floating point number `2.94867828828E+17`. Which, when resolved by `number_format()` gives the original number.

How can i get the correct value, please?

This needs to be able to be able work with different numbers.

Comment: are you using a 32 bit OS?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic or Why don’t my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @John It's running on a shared hosting server, which is 64-bit. (i686)

Comment: what is the value of PHP_INT_MAX on your machine?

Comment: @airza PHP_INI_MAX is 2147483647

Comment: For me, `number_format(294867828828426241 - 1)` returns `294,867,828,828,426,240` as expected (32-bit OS, `PHP_INT_MAX` = `2147483647`).

Comment: @webbiedave How did i overlook the obvious? That worked for me. Thank you. I used `number_format(294867828828426241 - 1,0,'','')` to remove the commas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php) extension you can use this:

```
$a = bcsub('294867828828426241', '1');

echo $a; // 294867828828426240
```

However, testing on my 64-bit server your code should work correctly. I'm not sure, but you can check to see if increasing the [precision](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) directive in your `php.ini` will make any difference. I have mine set at 14.

Comment: I seem to get -1 from that code. However, `precision` in php.ini is set to 12. When I set it to above 18, i get `294867828828426239`.

Comment: @cryptic; you need to embrace the number with quotes; "294867828828426241" or yields -1 on 32bit.

Comment: @qeremy yeah just saw that, it expects the inputs to be numeric strings. But the odd thing it works fine on my server, no errors, but I am using PHP 5.5alpha3 with the latest BCMath compiled, so maybe it's allowed without quotes in later versions. OP says he is using 64-bit.

Comment: @qeremy Thank you! This works as well as what was said in the comments.

Comment: @crypticツ It could work well on 64bit but the problem is 32bit doesn't know what is 294867828828426241, knows only max 2147483647. :) and cos of this, needs quotes for any function for numbers that bigger than 2147483647.