# PHP: Error with bigint number

Tags: php, php-5.3

I've got a strange error. See the code

```
    $val1 = pow(2, 64);
    $val2 = $val1 - 1;
    echo number_format($val1, 0, '', '') . "<br/>";
    echo number_format($val2, 0, '', '') . "<br/>";
```

and it`s output

```
18446744073709551616
18446744073709551616
```

Why $val2 has value 18446744073709551616 when it must be 18446744073709551615?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14572704/1190388

Comment: Related: [PHP Math Precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision).

Answer (score 1):

It's because $val1 became float and floating precision isn't that high. Look at [Float precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) Just look at example from manual `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` should be rather 8 but on my PC it also return 7 (as in manual)

If you want to use such big numbers you should probably use dedicated PHP libraries or [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)